# Lightning - retrieve picklist values available for RecordType

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, picklist, record-type, filters

How can I show only picklist values allowed for a specific Record Type?

For example:

Case.Status values are `"Pending", "Open", "Closed"`

- Case RecordType1 only allows the `Pending` value
- Case RecordType2 allows `Open` and `Closed` values

I'm developing a Lightning component in a Visualforce Page but I haven't found a convenient lightning-way to do this. 
I'm looking for a stable solution, that allows me to remove the component from the VF page at any time.

In Visualforce I used to invoke the `describeLayout` API offered with connection.js and it worked well:

```
sforce.connection.describeLayout(
    selectedObjectType,
    new Array(recordTypeId), {
       onSuccess: handleDescribeLayoutSuccess,
       onFailure: handleDescribeLayoutFailure
    }
);
```

So I tried to import connection.js in my Lightning component using ltng:require and retrieving the SessionId with a server-side action. 
It works well with **Locker Service** disabled, but when it is enabled the describeLayout response always enter in the `onFailure` callback.

The data provided to the onFailure function shows the layout describe in XML, but it is treated as an error.

The response `data` is below (just skipped part of the inner describe):

```
Remote invocation failed, due to: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
      <LimitInfoHeader><limitInfo><current>2</current><limit>15000</limit><type>API REQUESTS</type></limitInfo>
      </LimitInfoHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
       <describeLayoutResponse>
         <result><-- correct layout describe, skipped for readability --></result>    
       </describeLayoutResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope> status code:
```

Comment: I hope this sort of thing isn't still necessary, but this is what I did for [Picklist values by record type for AngularJS UI](https://force201.wordpress.com/2015/06/01/picklist-values-by-record-type-for-angularjs-ui/) 18 months ago to provide the data to the JavaScript based UI.

Comment: Can you add some more detail around what you mean by "not working"? That is pretty vague and not very helpful.

Comment: Lightning's content security and session ID policy does not allow the use of any API endpoints - has been that way from day one and is not something Locker is responsible for - what makes you believe this is a Locker issue? Should not work in a Lightning Compinent regardless of Locker being activated. Is this a LC in Visualforce scenario or are you simply trying to port existing VF ways of doing things to Lightning?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The sessionId was retrieved via a server-side method and it worked since LockerService was activated in our org. @DougChasman are there any ways to do this (filter picklist values for record type) in a "lightning way"?

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the UI API from your lightning component's apex controller to retrieve this information. It's not ideal because you have to use an API call into your own org, but at least it is now possible.

See [the salesforce documentation on the UI API here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_picklist_values.htm).

The callout would be `/ui-api/object-info/{objectApiName}/picklist-values/{recordTypeId}/{fieldApiName}`. This retrieves picklist values based on the record type ID you pass it.

Comment: Using the above API and salesforce documentation I am not getting any response. Although using /ui-api/object-info/{objectApiName} I am getting the object info.

Comment: Doesn't mean this answer is wrong. You are just calling the API incorrectly.

Comment: @RishiGolyan I just tested this API call using a sandbox and Workbench and I was able to successfully retrieve picklist values from the Account object for a specific record type. Make sure you are calling it as per the [get started intro docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_intro.htm), and you are calling it against a [supported object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_get_started_supported_objects.htm#ui_api_get_started_supported_objects)

Answer (score 2):

I just found this for LWC, that allows you to get the picklist options for a record type
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values_record

So in theory you could write a generic LWC that you pass the object, record type name, field name and it would return the list of options.

Here is an example from their git repo - https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/wireGetPicklistValuesByRecordType

Answer (score 1):

There is a component in Lighting : (check [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/specification) here)

```
lightning:recordEditForm
```

It is working fine **without any** other **apex** or **controller** code :

```
<lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.case.Id}" recordTypeId="{!v.recordTypeId}" objectApiName="Case">
       <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1">
             <lightning:inputField fieldName="Status" value="{!v.case.Status}"/>
        </div>
</lightning:recordEditForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to go get this working with the wire adapters. LWCs now provide [getPicklistValues](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values) to get picklist values based on record type

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
 import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
 
 
 export default class PicklistTest extends LightningElement {
     @api recordTypeId;
     @api fieldApiName;
     picklistValues;
 
     @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: this.recordTypeId, fieldApiName: this.fieldApiName })
     wiredNewWorkload({ data, error }) {
         if (data) {
             this.picklistValues = data.values;
             this.dispatchEvent('picklistvalueload', {
                 detail: this.picklistValues
             });
         }
         if (error) {
             console.error('Error in retrieving picklist values!' + JSON.stringify(error));
         }
     }
 }
```

`recordTypeId` and `fieldApiName` (Case.Status) can be set inside the parent Aura component which can get the picklist values based on  `picklistvalueload` event.